# For a convex body $K\subset R^n$, does the quantity $\min_{t>0} E[t^{-1} \|tg - \pi_K( t g)\|_2]$ have a name? Where has it been studied?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

Consider a convex compact set $K\subset R^n$ (with non-empty interior if that helps).

Let $\Pi_K:R^n\to K$ be the projection onto $K$, defined as
$$
\Pi_K(x) = \operatorname{argmin}_{k\in K} \|k-x\|
$$
where, throughout, $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm.

In a problem in convex geometry (random linear transform of $K$), I am encountering the quantities
$$
\inf_{t>0} \frac{E[\|tg - \Pi_K(t g)\|]}{t},
\qquad
\inf_{t>0} \frac{E[\|tg - \Pi_K(t g)\|^2]^{1/2}}{t}.
$$
Above, $g\in N(0,I_n)$ and the expectation is with respect to the distribution of $g$. It would still be of interest if $g$ were replaced by a uniform random vector on the sphere $S^{n-1}$.

If $K$ were a subspace, these quantities would capture the dimension.
For a cone $K$ pointed at 0, these quantities reduce to the statistical dimension studied in [1]. I am wondering if these quantities have been studied, if they are known to have equivalent definitions related to other properties of $K$.

---

[1]: Dennis Amelunxen, Martin Lotz, Michael B. McCoy, Joel A. Tropp, Living on the edge: phase transitions in convex programs with random data, Information and Inference: A Journal of the IMA, Volume 3, Issue 3, September 2014, Pages 224–294, https://doi.org/10.1093/imaiai/iau005